# Finding the right regexes to aggregate logs?

Tags: python, regex, logging

I want to find all the logs with a 'similar' error message, and count the occurrences of each type of log. The problem is that there's frequently some dynamic part of the error message.

For example, given error messages like

```
"Didn't accept value 3 for parameter foo"
"Didn't accept value 6 for parameter bar"
"Could not open file 'my_file.json' because: it does not exist"
"Could not open file 'my_other_file.json' because: it is not 
formatted correctly"
```

I'd like to be able to count these log occurrences so that I end up with output like:

```
"Didn't accept value * for parameter *" -- 2 counts
"Could not open file * because: it does not exist" -- 2 counts
```

The problem with writing regular expressions is that there's a huge variety of log message formats coming from several teams. I'd have to write dozens upon dozens of regexes to end up with counts, and I'd still have a very long tail of uncounted log messages

Is there some way to detect when logs have some dynamic part, and aggregate them?

Comment: A general approach (but error prone) can be `difflib` module and checking for similarities between the messages.

Comment: Something with difflib seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
import re

logs = [
    "Didn't accept value 3 for parameter foo",
    "Didn't accept value 6 for parameter bar",
    "Could not open file 'my_file.json' because: it does not exist",
    "Could not open file 'my_other_file.json' because: it is not formatted correctly",
]

counts = {
    "Didn't accept value * for parameter *": 0,
    "Could not open file * because: *": 0
}

for log in logs:
    s = re.search(r"Didn't accept value \d+ for parameter \w+", log)
    if s:
        counts["Didn't accept value * for parameter *"] += 1
        continue
    s = re.search(r"Could not open file '[^']+' because: \w+", log)
    if s:
        counts["Could not open file * because: *"] += 1
        continue

print(counts)
```

Comment: Nope. The problem with writing regular expressions is that there's a huge variety of log message formats coming from several teams. I'd have to write dozens upon dozens of regexes to end up with counts, and I'd still have a very long tail of uncounted log messages